# Getting error using EXECUTE('UPDATE..') on a MySQL server from SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, execute, linked-server

I intend to do:

```
EXECUTE('UPDATE tableA SET campaignkey = ''20170101'' where storekey = 16
 and campaignkey LIKE ''%,%''') at MYLINKEDSERVER
```

but I get the error that:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; [...] for the right syntax to use near 'where storekey = 16 and campaignkey LIKE '%,%''

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? To me it seems like I might have one `'` too many on my `LIKE` statement, but I have Always used `''` to indicate a non-numeric value. I don't want to fiddle with this to prevent updating far too many values on this server.

campaignkey is non-numeric (I Believe varchar) and storekey is integer.

### Edit

I must not use OPENQUERY() because it is not set up correctly, and this is a urgent update.

### Edit 2

Seems like it is because of apostrophes `'`s in the EXECUTE statement.

When I conduct:

```
select * from openquery(linkedserver,'Select * from tableA where storekey = 16 
and campaignkey = ''20170826,151''')
```

it works, but when using:

```
EXECUTE('Select * from tableA where storekey = 16 
and campaignkey = ''20170826,151''') at linkedserver
```

I get the error that I need to check the manual by the `where` clause. From googling it appears however that the correct syntax in fact is:

```
EXECUTE('UPDATE TableX SET StringVar = ''stringValue'' WHERE intVar = 3 
AND stringVar = ''xxxxx''') AT LinkedServer
```

I don't know why this won't work for me.. I have tried many combinations of `''`, `'"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
update openquery(linkedserver,'Select * from tableA where storekey = 16 
and campaignkey = ''20170826,151''')
set campaignkey = '20170101'
```

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to use OPENQUERY. The server is not set up for that (some error about bin logs or something like that) and I am not authorized to conduct those kind of changes. Thanks for input however, it is a useful Query I use when its possible.